# Handle multiple radio buttons in a tree view with React

Tags: reactjs

I have a dataset with menu items and nested sub-menu items, coming from a GET request.  With that, I render a table in a react-hook-form for assigning access permissions on each menu item.

```
[
  {
    moduleId: 2,
    moduleName: "Menu 1",
    permission: 0,
    subModuleList: [
      {
        moduleId: 7,
        moduleName: "Menu 1.1",
        permission: 0,
        subModuleList: null
      },
      {
        moduleId: 8,
        moduleName: "Menu 1.2",
        permission: 0,
        subModuleList: [
          {
            moduleId: 11,
            moduleName: "Menu 1.2.1",
            permission: 0,
            subModuleList: null
          },
          {
            moduleId: 33,
            moduleName: "Menu 1.2.2",
            permission: 0,
            subModuleList: null
          },
          {
            moduleId: 49,
            moduleName: "Menu 1.2.3",
            permission: 0,
            subModuleList: null
          },
          {
            moduleId: 68,
            moduleName: "Menu 1.2.4",
            permission: 0,
            subModuleList: null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Each table row is a menu item and has 2 radio buttons (no access & read) if it has children, and 3 radio buttons (no access, read & read/write) if is without children.

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish, is that each time a radio button is clicked on a child menu item, I want all the parent menu items to update as well with a relevant checked radio button. I feel really stacked on how to achieve this with react.

[Here is a code sandbox link with all the current implementations.](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-bush-ycl575?file=/src/PermissionsTable.js)

Example use case: When checking the menu item **Menu 1.2.2** with read or read/write permissions, the **Menu 1.2** and **Menu 1** should also have checked the read permission

[image]

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

So after some thought, I came up with a solution. The first step is to identify all the parents of each child is clicked.

```
function getPath(object, search) {
  if (object.moduleId === search) return [object.moduleName];
  else if (object.subModuleList || Array.isArray(object)) {
    let children = Array.isArray(object) ? object : object.subModuleList;
    for (let child of children) {
      let result = getPath(child, search);
      if (result) {
        if (object.moduleId) result.unshift(object.moduleName);
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This function returns an array of names of all the parent elements. Then I had to find these parent elements on my dataset and update their values based on my needs. There is also a check if the parent element has children, and one or more are checked with value > 0, to retain the parent as checked.

```
//get all parent objects
const findId = (object, key, searchTerm, newValue) => {
  if (object === null) return;
  if (Array.isArray(object)) {
    for (const obj of object) {
      findId(obj, key, searchTerm, newValue);
    }
  } else {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && object[key] === searchTerm) {
      if (object.subModuleList !== null) {
        if (newValue >= "1") newValue = "1";

        if (newValue === "0") {
          const childActive = object.subModuleList.some(
            (element) => element.permission !== "0"
          );
          
          if (childActive) {
            newValue = "1";
          } else {
            newValue = "0";
          }
        }
      }
      object.permission = newValue;
      return object;
    }
    for (const k of Object.keys(object)) {
      if (typeof object[k] === "object") {
        findId(object[k], key, searchTerm, newValue);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

[Here you can find an updated code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-moon-fc6mmk?file=/src/PermissionsTable.js)

I hope that someone will benefit from this solution. Also, I want to mention that the code presented here, is also from answers of other devs on other topics.